# UITableView - deleting a row causes a crash

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a `UITableView` with a custom header that includes a `UITextField`. I enter text in that `textfield` and tap “done” on the `keyboard` to dismiss the keyboard - works fine.

I have a `UIActionSheet` that is launched to confirm wanting to delete a row in the table. Tap "confirm" and the `UIActionSheet` is dismissed and the row is deleted - works fine.

But, if I enter text in the `textfield` (and dismiss the keyboard) and then try to delete a row - the app freezes for a moment on the `UIActionSheet` and then crashes.

This is the crash report I get.

```
Thread 0 Crashed:

0   CoreFoundation        0x00004260 __CFTypeCollectionRetain + 16
1   CoreFoundation        0x00005e38 __CFDictionaryRetainValue + 20
2   CoreFoundation        0x000054a8 __CFBasicHashAddValue + 100
3   CoreFoundation        0x00005158 CFDictionarySetValue + 68
4   UIKit                 0x000e3472 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateWithItems:withOldRowData:oldRowRange:newRowRange:context:] + 1730
5   UIKit                 0x000e281e -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 4770
6   UIKit                 0x0012a4d6 -[UITableView _updateRowsAtIndexPaths:updateAction:withRowAnimation:] + 198
7   UIKit                 0x0012a3de -[UITableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:] + 14
8   Tracker8              0x00012502 -[TrackerTableViewController actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:] (PriceTableViewController.m:313)
9   UIKit                 0x00369596 -[UIActionSheet(Private) _buttonClicked:] + 186
```

Any suggestions why the two elements work individually but not in sequence? Thanks for your help.

Update: More testing of my code shows the crash only happens on a device running iOS 4.1. It does not crash on devices running iOS 5.1 or iOS 6.0. This leads me to think I'm dealing with an old, probably known, bug.

I've worked around it by positioning the tableview below a simulated "header view" created in IB using a label and textfield. No more crashes if the textfield is edited and then a row is deleted.

For those interested in recreating/explaining the crash here is the implementation code:

```
@synthesize table;
@synthesize array;

#pragma mark View Lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableArray *staticArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"This is the 1st row.",
                        @"This is the 2nd row.", @"This is the 3rd row.",
                        @"This is the 4th row.", @"This is the 5th row.",
                        @"This is the 6th row.", @"This is the 7th row.",
                        @"This is the 8th row.", @"This is the 9th row.",
                        @"This is the 10th row.", nil];

    self.array = staticArray;
    [staticArray release];
}

#pragma mark TableView Data Source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return [self.array count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        [cell autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
                                        forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {
        // remove selected object from the data array
        [self.array removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        // Delete the row from the table.
        [self.table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] 
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];                
    } 
}

#pragma mark TableView Delegate

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // custom header view containing a label and a textfield
    UIView *headerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)]autorelease];
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    headerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    UILabel *pLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 21)] autorelease];
    pLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    pLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    pLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    pLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    pLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0];
    pLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    pLabel.minimumFontSize = 10.0;
    pLabel.text = @"Table Header"; 

    UITextField *pField = [[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 18, 280, 31)] autorelease];
    pField.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    pField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    pField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    pField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    pField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
    pField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    pField.minimumFontSize = 10.0;
    pField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
    pField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    pField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    pField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    pField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    pField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    pField.delegate = self; 
    pField.placeholder = @"tap to enter text";

    // add label and textField to the header view
    [headerView addSubview:pLabel];
    [headerView addSubview:pField];

    return headerView;  
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 50.0;
}

#pragma mark TextField Delegate

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{   
    // dismiss the keyboard
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}

#pragma mark Memory Management

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning 
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload 
{
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;

    self.table = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc 
{
    [table release];
    [array release];

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

To crash it, run it on a device with iOS 4.1 and follow these steps:

1. edit the textfield
2. dismiss the keyboard
3. swipe a row to delete
4. tap the delete button
5. CRASH!

Thanks for taking a look at this problem.

Comment: You need to post your code to get a better answer. Without seeing it, all I can say if that you have to make sure when you are adding and removing data to your tableview, you are making sure the size of the data is consistent.